# Netlify deployment - 500 Internal Server Error. on one pages

Tags: error-handling, netlify, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

Im trying to deploy my app with Netlify and Heroku.

Deployment works just fine - this is the URL:
https://fahrzeugliste-t5-kfz-neumayer.netlify.app/

Start page is working as intended, while clicking on "Fahrzeugliste" gets an 500 Internal Server Error.

This is the git repo for it:
https://github.com/TimoScheiler/fahrzeugliste

Answer (score 0):

Your function log here: https://app.netlify.com/sites/fahrzeugliste-t5-kfz-neumayer/functions/___netlify-handler, shows the problem. It says:

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://fahrzeugliste-t5.herokuapp.com/api/fahrzeug reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at /var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:273:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async getServerSideProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/fahrzeuge.js:234:34)
    at async Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:428:24)
    at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1149:38)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1241:28
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:64:36 {
  type: 'invalid-json'
}
```

If you go here: https://fahrzeugliste-t5.herokuapp.com/api/fahrzeug, you can indeed see that you don't get an expected response from your Heroku backend. You get a HTML page instead of a JSON response. You need to sort that out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to figure it out but it isnt working so far.

Comment: @FRBT Debugging your Heroku app's problem is unrelated to this thread. Please open a new thread for people to help with that.